# Determining Table to Paste to On The Fly

Tags: filemaker

How do I tell Filemaker what table to paste a value into based on the value? Is there a way to somehow have Filemaker paste a value into a table without hard coding the table name?

Using imported transaction data, I determine which ledger (table) the transaction should be posted to. But I can't seem to get the script to then post it into the right table based on the value.

[Screenshot of Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dobv1.png)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the thoughtful suggestions!

I found a way to do what I was thinking, @AndreasT your suggestion helped.

```
Case ( 

     Imported_Transactions::Debit_To = "Expenses_All"; "Expenses_All::Description";

     Imported_Transactions::Debit_To = "Liability_CrCard_BofA"; Liability_CrCard_BofA::Description;

     Imported_Transactions::Debit_To = "Liability_CrCard_CitiBusiness"; Liability_CrCard_CitiBusiness::Description;

  )
```

Using the Case function, I was able to get Filemaker to put the data in the right table. It took some doing, but by putting the tablename::field in quotes, it worked.

Ultimately, though, I found it easier to just use one table and field descriptors to store my data. Simplicity makes it easier to produce reports.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the conditional If script step to determine what table to insert data into based on your input.

Answer (score 0):

Set field by name[ tablename::fieldname ; value ]